# How to disable video's comments in youtube using the APIv3 with PHP?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the google-api-php-client to upload videos to youtube, it's using the last version of the API (v3) with OAuth, I'm looking for a way to disable comments to the videos I upload.

I found way to do it using JAVA and the legacy gdata API, but if I'm right, I can't use OAuth with it (and it's not supported by the google-api-php-client).

Comment: Please vote to provide the capability to disable commenting here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7664